# Creating a thumbnail in PHP store in different folder

Tags: php, image, file, upload

Hello I was looking at creating a thumbnail along with my main image. I would like it to be stored in a different folder than the original and be a maximum height of 400px. I have had a search around but it all seems too complex. I was looking for something fairly simple. I am new to the file uploading stuff. Below is the code I currently have.

```
// Configuration
  $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg', '.JPG', '.bmp', '.png', '.gif');
  $max_filesize = 100000000;
  $upload_path = 'artimages/';

  $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

// Random Number
  $randomnumber = rand(1, 1000000);
  $filename = $randomnumber.$filename;

// File Size
  if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
     die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

// File Type
  if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
     die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Check CHMOD 777
  if(!is_writable($upload_path))
     die('Fail');

// Upload File
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
        echo 'Success';
     else
        echo 'Fail';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will require PHP-GD

```
  // load image and get image size
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );
  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );

  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_width = $thumbWidth;
  $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

  // save thumbnail into a file
  imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks. What happens if the original image is smaller than the chosen thumb width?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that:

```
$tmp_path = /*the temp path of your picture*/;
$imagePath = /*the path of you uploaded picture*/;
$Thumbnail = /*the path of your thumbnail folder*/;

move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $imagePath);
copy($imagePath, $thumbnailPath);
```

So you will upload your image and just after that you will copy it in another location.

Comment: I need to resize the thumbnail as well

Comment: This answer will not resize the image.

Comment: Oh yes sorry! So the answer posted by Colin Schoen will be perfect.